# How to avoid writing explicit template arguments for an operator taking a compile-time value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

As per my previous post, I learned that I cannot use a function parameter as an argument to a compile-time construct. This is because the parameter to function is expected at run-time, but the template argument is processed at *compile-time*.

Since I unfortunately cannot use `constexpr` on a parameter, I decided to use template argument. It works fine but with respect to looks I wouldn't say it's the best alternative:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class... Args>
struct type_list
{
    std::tuple<Args...> var;

    type_list(Args&&... args) : var(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    template <std::size_t N>
    auto operator[](std::size_t)
        -> typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Args...>>::type&&
    {
        return std::move(std::get<N>(var));
    }
};

int main()
{
    type_list<int, int, bool> list(2, 4, true);

    int i = list.operator[]<0>(0); // How can I avoid this?
}
```

Is there some way I can avoid this? How can give a constant expression to a function while avoid the explicit operator syntax? Is it possible with macros?

Comment: Is there something wrong with using a tuple directly and `std::get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class template that wraps a compile-time constant (or use this one http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/int.html), make the parameter of the operator [] templated, and pass values of wrapped constants to the operator. The declaration of your operator changes to this:

```
template <typename T>
auto operator[](T) -> ...
```

Inside the operator replace N with T::value if you use boost MPL

Use of the operator changes to this:

```
int i = list[int_<0>()];
```